# Room SQLite file - Ensure all changes are flushed and no I/O in the middle of file uploading

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

We are using Android Architecture Components's Room, to perform database read/ write operation.

We know the location of the SQLite file, which the Room is writing.

We have a requirement : When the app quit, we would like to launch a background process (Using Android Jetpack WorkManager), to upload the SQLite file, to user cloud storage.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (this.isFinishing()) {
        // Use Android Jetpack WorkManager, to 
        // upload SQLite file written by Room to user cloud storage.
```

---

Our concern is, how can we ensure just before we are performing uploading

- All changes performed by Room, is flushed to SQLite file.
- In the middle of SQLite file uploading, there are no read/write operation on the SQLite file, to avoid we are uploading a "half-written" (corrupted) file.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no good way to determine this automatically. If the user manually chooses some sort of backup/upload option (e.g., toolbar button), you could attempt to proactively close the database, do your upload, then reopen it, though I'm not sure how well this works either. This is one of those areas that I keep meaning to experiment on and have to keep postponing due to other work that piles up...

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that I would propose, but you have to implement it in parts:

First, you may require [ProcessLifeCycle](https://proandroiddev.com/react-to-app-foreground-and-background-events-with-processlifecycleowner-96278e5816fa) that will help you determine whether app is in Foreground or Background.

While app goes to background, schedule a job that performs below tasks:

Copy database it to some temporary storage (I prefer Cache Storage)
Then, start uploading that database to Server.

This way your database won't be left in some inconsistent state in any ways.

Comment: But, how do you ensure during copy process, all changes already flushed, and no IO happen on that file?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng For now, I could think of one way i.e. If we could have a Transaction Table, then we won't have to worry about IO stuff. What do you say about this ?